# Custom module integration with Views3 for D7?

Tags: views, 7

I have a custom module named ta_module which alters the user registration form.
But since I updated Views to version **7.x-3.0 - rc1**, I have like a hundred errors barely the same as the following :

`Warning: include_once(/{PRIVATE - DRUPAL ROOT FOLDER}/sites/all/modules/ta_module/views/theme/theme.inc) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in _theme_process_registry() (line 413 of /{PRIVATE - DRUPAL ROOT FOLDER}/includes/theme.inc).`

`Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening '/{PRIVATE - DRUPAL ROOT FOLDER}/sites/all/modules/ta_module/views/theme/theme.inc' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in _theme_process_registry() (line 413 of /{PRIVATE - DRUPAL ROOT FOLDER}/includes/theme.inc).`

It seems like I need to create a /views/theme/theme.inc in my custom module folder. BUT TWO QUESTIONS REMAIN :

**- Do I leave this file blank or am I supposed to put things in it ?**

**- Do I have to create other folders/files for Views not to interfere with my module ?**

Thks for reading !  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried clearing the cache?

The error is there because some module, expects that there is such a file and tries to include it. It could be a direct result of whatever views integration you are doing.

The error will go away if the file exists, an empty file with `<?php` is enough.